# Prefix all numbers in a file with a string using sed

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

Using sed, awk or possibly something else I would like to prefix all numbers in file with a string e.g.

input:

```
sometext(0, 456)
sometext(01, 10)
```

output:

```
sometext(somestring0, somestring456)
sometext(somestring01, somestring10)
```

I have attempted using sed but my skills are limited so I have not managed to produce any meaningful output.

Using OSX10.11 so I know that sed has slightly different behaviour in BSD than under other *nix's.

I also have perl and python at hand if that solves this better but sed and awk are preferred.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this sed command that matches and captures a number and in replacement prefixes it:

```
sed -E 's/[[:digit:]]+/somestring&/g' file

sometext(somestring0, somestring456)
sometext(somestring01, somestring10)
```

Please keep in mind that `somestring` should not contain special replacements constructs like `&, \1, \2, \3` etc.

Comment: Or `sed 's/[0-9][0-9]*/somestring&/g' file` for portability across all seds.

Comment: add maybe the `(` and `,` in the pattern, if there is a digit in the `sometext` it give a wrong result  `sed -E 's/\([(,][[:blank:]]*\)\([0-9][0-9]*\)/\1somestring\2/g'`